# ¿Cómo puedo abrir una app con un boton en ionic 5?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic, ionic-framework

Como puedo abrir una app, desde un boton en mi app de ionic 5??
que plugin se pueden usar o se puede usar el InAppBrowser??

la idea es mostrar un boton para poder abrir una app que se esta desarrollando pero como se puede hacer para que en caso de que esa app no este instalada te mande a la playstore, o si el caso que este instalada te abra esa app??

Comment: Yo estuve usando ionic por un tiempo, en especifico la version 4, me parecio muy comodo, pero la verdad en la actualidad no lo recomiendo mucho en cuanto a aspectos de seguridad y plugins, sin embargo si ya tienes todo el proyecto en ionic, me parece que una forma de hacer que se abra una app especifica es haciendo un link (una etiqueta `a`) que haga referencia al nombre en paquete de la app que quieres abrir, para mas informacion mira esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978319/open-application-on-mobile-from-html-link